# Source Tree - How to revert the pushed commit

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I have 2 remote branchs which are dev and master.
I always develop in dev branch and merge the change to master branch.
But I found I have accidentally use master branch to develop and then commit and push to the remote.

[image]

Is there any way to revert it, like cancelling the last commit without making new history?
I am using source tree

Comment: Working alone on the project? If so, it'll be trivial

Comment: Yes. How should i do? Can keep the changes in local?

Answer (score 2):

**(CLI solution - but a SourceTree solution is still welcome)**

---

Since you work alone on the repo without banch permissions scheme blocking you from pushing, your only problem is to find on which commit was `master` before your last push.

You can find that simply from your `git log --oneline master` output if you just committed a few times. Find the last merge from `dev`, note that commit hash, let's call it `<oldMasterHash>`.

Then just do

```
# move dev where master is now
git checkout -B dev master
git push

# now let's "repair" master
git checkout master
git reset --hard <oldMasterHash>
# here we'll need --force to push since this is a history rewrite
git push --force
```

...and you'll be all set, local and remote.

Comment: @CCCC I'm afraid I can't. But these steps can guide you through your GUI choices I guess?